# Laravel public css 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

При попытки сервера подключить css файл или js по пути http://example.com/css/app.css  получаю 404 файлы стандартные из коробки. 
причина возможно в том что laravel пытается перейти по контролеру css а он не прописан в router.php получа. ошибку RouteCollection.php line 145 при прямом открытии css файла

настройки apache

```
<Directory /home/h63546/data/www/example.com>
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php3
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php4
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .phtml
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
<Directory /home/h63546/data/www/*.example.com>
    Options +ExecCGI
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php3
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php4
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .php5
    FCGIWrapper /home/h63546/data/php-bin/php .phtml
</Directory>
<VirtualHost 91.200.40.54:8080>
    ServerName cosmetolog.net.ua
    DocumentRoot /home/h63546/data/www/example.com
    SuexecUserGroup h63546 h63546 
    CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log
    ServerAlias *.example.com www.example.com
    ServerAdmin 
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/h63546/data/www/example.com/cgi-bin/
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/h63546/data/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: из предыдущего вопроса: покажите что в установках apache для данного сервера прописано. Дополните в вопросе

Comment: @zhenyab обновил вопрос

Comment: DocumentRoot должен указывать на public и будет иметь следующий вид /home/h63546/data/www/example.com/public

Comment: @zhenyab не решило проблему. Все результат такой  же

Comment: а после изменений apache рестартанули? Если, да, то все равно нужно как следует настроить все. В документации Laravel все написано, и если сделать все по документации - проблем не возникает.

Comment: @zhenyab все заработало вы были правы, т.к. прямого доступа нет делаю это через тех поддержку хостинга, был необходим рестарт

Comment: @zhenyab сделайте коменнтарий ответом чтобы я его отметил как правильный